# SwiftUI FocusState not working when TextField is in ToolbarItem

Tags: swift, swiftui, uitextfield

My purpose is to auto focus and remove focus.

The page that is launched for the first time can automatically get the focus, but if you push to the next page, it will automatically fail.

**works this way**

```swift
struct SearchTextFieldView: View {
    
    @FocusState var focused: Field?
    @State var username: String = ""
    
    enum Field: Int, Hashable {
        case name
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    focused = nil
                } label: {
                    Text("Remove Focuse")
                }
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        focused = .name
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    TextField("user name", text: $username)
                        .focused($focused, equals: .name)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .padding(4)
                        .border(.secondary)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

**push to the next page doesn't work**

```swift
struct SearchRootView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                SearchTextFieldPushView()
            } label: {
                Text("Search")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SearchTextFieldPushView: View {
    
    @FocusState var focused: Field?
    @State var username: String = ""
    
    enum Field: Int, Hashable {
        case name
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                focused = nil
            } label: {
                Text("Remove Focuse")
            }
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    focused = .name
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                TextField("user name", text: $username)
                    .focused($focused, equals: .name)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .padding(4)
                    .border(.secondary)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the way I use it? still bug.

Comment: I posted an answer on this other question, please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78127540/4691224

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `NavigationView` keeps the FocusState from the main view. But you can pass it down to the child view:

```
struct SearchRootView: View {
    
    @FocusState var focused: Field? // define here

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                SearchTextFieldPushView(focused: _focused) // pass down here
            } label: {
                Text("Search")
            }
        }
    }
}

enum Field {
    case name
}

struct SearchTextFieldPushView: View {
    
    @FocusState var focused: Field?
    
    @State var username: String = ""

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                focused = nil
            } label: {
                Text("Remove Focus")
            }

            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    focused = .name
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                TextField("user name", text: $username)
                    .focused($focused, equals: Field.name)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .padding(4)
                    .border(.secondary)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: my feeling is there should be a more straight-forward way ... but at least it does the job.

Comment: And I test can't contain `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode`, otherwise it won't work

Comment: @ChrisR Hmm, this doesn't work in iOS 16. Any ideas?

Comment: @robinst You are right, this doesn't work at least if having the Textfield under .toolbar ToolbarItem . I have an open question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74245149/focusstate-textfield-not-working-within-toolbar-toolbaritem check it out...

Comment: Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: The answer I posted here is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78127540/4691224